# IPad keyboard "Hide button"

Tags: objective-c, ipad, keyboard

How can I interact with the button  "hide keypad" 
In IPad numeric pad.
I need to add validation for this button.
Or how I can switch off this button?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the delegate method for the keyboard hide button .But I think You can solve this by adding the following code to you .m file

1.Add the following  code to your viewWillAppear function

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                    selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
2.Add the following code to viewWillDisappear function

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                              object:nil];
```

3.Declare function in .h file

```
     -(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notify;
```

4.Define function in .m file

-(void)keyboardWillHide :(NSNotification*)notif
{

```
//Add the code for What you wish to do after the key board hide.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the moment when the user hits that button

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    //your code here
    return YES;
}
```